# How to change voices in pyttsx3 modlue of python

Tags: python, pip, pyttsx3

I am using the pyttsx3 module for text-to-speech in one of my python projects, but I am not able to choose a male/female option for voices. I read the documentation given on https://pypi.org/project/pyttsx3/ where it says use voices[0].id/voices[1].id for male and female voices respectively. However, that does not seem to work as there is no significant difference between the 2 voices.

My code:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()

voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)

engine.say("Hello World!")
engine.runAndWait()
```

Any idea how to change the voice and also is there a way to change the language of text-to-speech...something similar to auto-translate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')       #getting details of current voice
#engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)  #changing index, changes voices. o for male
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)   #changing index, changes voices. 1 for female
```

this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

To change the voice to either female or male, use

```
import pyttsx3 as p
engine = p.init()
voice = engine.getProperty('voice')
#for female
engine.setProperty(voice, "!v/f1")
#for male
engine.setProperty(voice, "!v/m1")
engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but it doesn't work. There are no errors shown, but at the same time, there is still no difference between the male and the female voices.

Comment: It takes from m1 to m5, f1 to f5

Comment: yeah, I tried that, but as I said earlier, there's no difference.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! :)